# Hotkey for cursor movement in windows sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, hotkeys

I use emacs and always use ctrl-n/p to move the cursor up/down one line.

My teammates use sublime text and they always use MOUSE!!
I googled a bit but can't find a keybinding of cursor-up/down in windows sublime.

How do you move your cursor in windows sublime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your user key bindings.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+n"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+p"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true} }
```

If you are an emacs user, you may also be interested in trying out https://github.com/grundprinzip/sublemacspro